# React - using render props with inherited props

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm working on a Form Item component in React which uses Render Props to pass down data to a child component within it which acts as the form control e.g Input, Select, Textarea etc.

The render props are working fine between the Form Item and the Input. However I'd now like to wrap the FormItem in another component (Template) in order to show it in a Storybook application. The template component will have props which then need to be passed down to the Form Item which will then pass it on to the Input. The code structure is as per below. However I'm struggling to work out how to pass props from Grandparent to Parent. Any help would be amazing:

```js
const GrandParent = ({ gpProp1, gpProp2, ...props}) => {
    console.log({
      gpProp1,
      gpProp2,
    });
    return <Parent render={(props) => <Child {...props} />} />
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. The props passed in via the Grandparent and rendered by the parent cannot be named the same so it becomes:

```js
const GrandParent = ({ gpProp1, gpProp2, ...props}) => {
    console.log({
      gpProp1,
      gpProp2,
    });
    return <Parent render={(renderProps) => <Child {...renderProps} {...props} />} />
  })
}
```